# how can an Xcode swift app call functions in a swift static lib?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two xcode projects (1) a swift static lib, and (2) a swift app.

What are the steps to have the swift app call a function in the swift lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new workspace: File > New Workspace or <kbd>^</kbd> +  <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
2. Add both your `.xcodeproj` files to the workspace by drag and drop.
3. Select your main project in the workspace, and under the General tab, in Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content, click the + icon at the bottom and add your library's .a file as a dependency.
4. On the file of your project where you want to use a function from your library, import the module (`import YourStaticLib`)
5. Use your library functions :)

Note: Make sure the classes/structs/funcs you want to use are declared as `public` in your library.

Comment: Is @objc necessary?

Comment: @DougNull no, is not needed

Comment: This solution worked great.  But how can I add only lib's binary executable?  I need to send lib to consultants and don't want to reveal source code.

Comment: To distriubute your library you can distribute the compiled source (using a script to create a fat binary), but this is kind of hacky and not supported by Apple. Luckily since Xcode 11 we have XCFrameworks, which allows you to distribute frameworks for both simulators and real devices architectures. You can check this article to create your XCFramework: https://anuragajwani.medium.com/how-to-build-universal-ios-static-libraries-using-xcframework-a3f70f998c38